# non-US PhD's with extensive course work

Tags: phd, united-states, europe

I think I understand the general difference between US and European PhD.

**US**

1. GRE is compulsory to get admitted to any PhD programs.
2. First we get admitted to the institution.
3. Need to do extensive course work though if one has masters.
4. Will decide about the area of PhD only after completing the course
       work.

**Europe & Australia**

1. GRE is not compulsory, but might help to improve the chance of
   getting an admission.
2. We will know the research area in the beginning.
3. Most seems to have no course work or little course work.

If I am right it seems both have its own advantages and disadvantages.

I want to apply for a PhD with extensive course work (in the beginning of PhD) but I must know which area I'll be doing my PhD when i get admitted and the PhD duration must be more than ones without any course work (i expect around 1+4 years of funding).

What are my best options considering the above concerns ?

**Note:** I am looking for PhD in Theoretical Physics

Comment: Why do you want to do extensive course work? For example, I have to take a number of credits during my PhD, but nothing stops me from sitting in as many extra classes over that number as I see they will help me.

Comment: @Davidmh thts right. but i have  reasons to believe that it'd be the best option for me in the long run, if the first one year (atleast) is only course wok and it is funded, quite like the US.

Comment: But why? I have the feeling this may be another instance of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Davidmh well.... My masters was not particularly meant to do theoretical work in basic science (from my experience and point of view). To be precise my masters was neither in physics or theoretical physics, but in optics. I think if i have to do course work in PhD, rather than directly going into research, that would strengthen my knowledge and i believe this is the best option i have.

Comment: I think the usual solution in non-US systems would be to take a second masters (for coursework) before embarking on a PhD (and thus going into research).  It sounds like your focus on a PhD is mainly because PhDs are usually funded, and so maybe the question you should really ask is "How can I find a funded masters program in theoretical physics?"

Comment: @NateEldredge though it is an option, wasting 2 years on masters may not b a good idea. may be i can ask "what is the maximum duration for a PhD with course work (beginning) in europe (in theoretical physics) ?"

Comment: It isn't necessarily "wasted", in all probability you'll have to take more or less the same courses in a PhD if you didn't do them before (because you'll need them for your research).

Comment: @vonbrand thanx.but is it anyway possible to abtain a 4+1 phd in europe, quite similar to US phd duration ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a PhD in theoretical physics obtained in Germany: in particular

> GRE is not compulsory, but might help to improve the chance of getting an admission.

GRE is totally irrelevant.

> We will know the research area in the beginning.

this is mainly true all across Europe but however there are some departments whose research projects are to be decided on your way throughout graduation (it happens in Italy, for example). I had a very strict and detailed project to fully adhere to, but it might not always be the case (with corresponding advantages and disadvantages). Also notice that sometimes, for whichever reason, PhD students change projects along the way (mostly because they do not like it or because it is a dead end line of research).

> Most seems to have no course work or little course work.

Wrong. I had heavy teaching duties (three-four semesters), mandatory classes to attend and corresponding exams to take (it happens in other European countries too). Besides that, compulsory seminars and conferences to take part to.

As a general rule always determine with the department you are applying to what the local rules are: it is *very* department dependent and even in the same department different scholarships may get treated differently and have different loads. I would personally go for a research project I like and then manage the extra curricular activities accordingly: after all, the chances to get a position afterwards will **only** depend on your final PhD thesis (and related papers); nobody ever looks at the exams marks and classes you have taken.

Comment: good to know this. so u mean one has to do course work and exams mostly graduate level, before starting research work ?

Comment: but in that case what is the PhD duration (funding) ?.. is it more than typical european PhD's without any course work ?

Comment: *Before*, *after* or *during* depends on the local rules: in my case it was in parallel. PhD duration is officially three years, practically as long as your supervisor decides to award you the grant.

Comment: thanx. That is what i am concerned about. If the duration is same and one needs to do course work in parallel, is different. Is it possible that the course work is in the beginning and the duration is one more year considering the course work period, than the typical european PhD's ?

Comment: Again, there's no such thing as *typical European PhD*: Europe is not one big country, rather it is the collection of many different things and each department has their own regulations. However, yes, the example you mention is typical in Italy, in some university, where you have 1+2 (1+3), the first year being devoted to course only.

Comment: thank you. I understand ur point. i mean by "typical" is 3 years. to be precise i mean 1+4 years ?

Comment: In my PhD (USA) had a set of rules taking a set of courses from different lines, many were taught very irregularly (if at all). I tried to puzzle a way through the maze. I gave up, talked to my (provisional) advisor. He told me "Oh, instead of two terms of foreign language, you'll have to take two terms of statistics. Go get a minor, approve your qualifying exam Oh, and do a thesis." There were two introductory courses suggested for all graduate students, I took them, and some "special topics" classes related to my research. I.e., don't take published regulations too seriously, ask around.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the area, you might be required to take an MPhil or Research Master. This is the equivalent to the coursework in the US, and then some electives related to your research area. Again, depending the Area, you will find that there are many universities that (at least try) to implement the US standard. In Business and Economics for example you have BGSE, Bonn, Toulouse, EUI, among many others that have a very "US" style doctoral program, just hidden by a (almost always mandatory) Master of Research plus the Doctoral Program which is mostly research.